# When is POSIX thread cancellation not immediate?

Tags: linux, pthreads, signals, cancellation

The POSIX specifies two types for thread cancellation type: `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS`, and `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` (set by `pthread_setcanceltype(3)`) determining when `pthread_cancel(3)` should take effect. By my reading, the POSIX manual pages do not say much about these, but Linux manual page says the following about `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS`:

> The thread can be canceled at any time.  (Typically, it will be canceled  immediately upon receiving a cancellation request, but the system doesn't guarantee this.)

I am curious about the meaning about *the system doesn't guarantee this*. I can easily imagine this happening in multicore/multi-CPU systems (before context switch). But what about single core systems:

1. Could we have a thread not cancelled immediately when cancellation is requested and cancellation is enabled (`pthread_setcancelstate(3)`) and cancel type set to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS`?
2. If yes, under what conditions could this happen?

I am mainly curious about Linux (LinuxThreads / NPTL), but also more generally about POSIX standard compliant way of viewing this cancellation business.

**Update/Clarification:** Here the real practical concern is usage of resources that are destroyed immediately after calling `pthread_cancel()` where the targeted thread have cancellation enabled and set to type `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS`!!! So the point really is: is there even a tiny possibility for the cancelled thread in this case to continue running normally after context switch (even for a very small time)?

Thanks for Damon's answer the question is reduced about signal delivery and handling in relation to the next context switch.

**Update-2:** I answered my own question to point that this is bad concern and that the underlying program design should be addressed in fundamentally different conceptual level. I wish this "wrong" question is useful for others wondering about mysteries of asynchronous cancellation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meaning is just what it says: It's not guaranteed to happen instantly. The reason for this is that a certain "liberty" for implementation details is needed and accounted for in the standard.

For example under Linux/NPTL, cancellation is implemented by sending signal nr. 32. The thread is cancelled when the signal is received, which usually happens at the next kernel-to-user switch, or at the next interrupt, or at the end of the time slice (which *may* accidentially be immediately, *but usually is not*). A signal is never received while the thread isn't running, however. So the real catch here is actually that *signals* are not necessarily received immediately.

If you think about it, it isn't even possible to do it much different, either. Since you can `phtread_cleanup_push` some handlers which the operating system must execute (it cannot just blast the thread out of existence!), the thread **must** necessarily run to be cancelled. There is no guarantee that *any* particular thread (including the one you want to cancel) is running at the exact time you cancel a thread, so there can be no guarantee that it is cancelled immediately.
Except of course, hypothetically, if the OS was implemented in a way as to block the calling thread and schedule the to-be-cancelled thread so it executes its handlers, and only unblocks pthread_cancel afterwards. But since `pthread_cancel` isn't specified as blocking, this would be an utterly nasty surprise. It would also be somewhat inacceptable because of interfering wtih execution time limits and scheduler fairness.

So, either your cancel type is "disable", then nothing happens. Or, it is "enable", and the cancel type is "deferred", then the thread cancels when calling a function that is listed as cancellation point in `pthreads(7)`.
Or, it is "asynchronous", then as stated above, the OS will do "something" to cancel the thread as soon as it deems appropriate -- not at a precise, well-defined time, but "soon". In the case of Linux, by sending a signal.

Comment: Now I check also LinuxThreads inside uClibc, which I am targeting with my cross-compilation, and it is the same implementation method there. Thanks for the excellent well-thought-out answer. Thread cancellation is ugly business.

Comment: It is actually rather obvious that thread cannot be destroyed before context switch and that context switch cannot arbitrary happen immediately after `pthread_cancel()` call. The more narrowed down and closer to the practical answer is as follows: when is the signal received and the signal handler run relative to the next context switch (in unicore architecture where we cannot have real concurrency)?

Comment: That's in the answer, too (2nd par). Signals (unless they're hardware-generated like e.g. `SIGSEGV´, those are received immediately as they occur) are received at a kernel-usermode switch, or when the task is scheduled, or when an interrupt occurs. That's explained in Michael Kerrisk's book somewhere under "signals". However, signals are only a Linux-specific implementation detail, and not the "general" answer in respect of pthreads.

Comment: Thanks about the clarification about the signal delivery. I have some time already wanted to buy that book... Maybe it is time.

Comment: In unicore machines without true concurrency, it seems the cancellation actually would start to manifest immediately upon the targeted thread starting to run again (when 
"task is scheduled") - assuming asynchronous cancellation mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wonder when the asynchronous cancellation happen, you are doing something terribly wrong.

1. **Following Standards:** You are eating ground below your feet by deliberately creating or allowing code to exist whose correctness depends on assumptions about the platform (single core, particular implementation, whatever). It is almost always better, if possible, to follow the standards (and document clearly when it is not possible). The name `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHROUNOUS` itself suggests the meaning *asynchronous*, which is different from immediate or even almost immediate. The original poster specifically states single core, but why should you allow code to exist that will break in non-deterministic ways, *when* your code is put to run in truly parallel machines (multiple cores or CPUs) where it is practically impossible to have guarantee of immediateness (this would require stopping the other cores from running or waiting for context switch or some other terrible hack which your OS/CPU is not going to support to support your unconventional wishes).
   *Asynchronous thread cancellation mode is not meant for guaranteed immediate cancellation of a thread. Hence it is a terribly confusing hack to use them in this way even if it would work.*
2. **Async-Safeness:** If you are concerned about the mechanism of asynchronous cancellation, it raises the suspicion that the threads in question (because of lack of independence) are maybe not *purely computational* or written in *async-cancel-safe* manner.

   POSIX specifies only three functions as async-cancel safe: `pthread_cancel(3)`, `pthread_setcancelstate(3)`, and `pthread_setcancelmode(3)` - see [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition, 2.9.5](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html). This cancellation mode is *only suitable for purely computational tasks* that do not call (other than purely computational) library functions; such code would not provide cancellation points if the threads were set to run in the default deferred cancellation mode. Hence *the rationale for defining such mode*.

   It *is* possible to write async-cancel-safe code by disabling cancellation during critical sections. But library writers (including POSIX library implementors) in general *should not* care about async-safetyness by reasons of following general convention, avoiding complexity, and even avoiding performance overhead. Because the library writers should not care, you should never expect async-safetyness unless it is explicitly stated otherwise.

   If your code is not async-safe (because for example calling other libraries, including POSIX/standard C libraries without temporarily disabling cancellation or changing cancellation mode) and asynchronous cancellation occurs, you might leak resources (memory, etc), leave behind inconsistent states and locked mutexes dead-locking other threads, and summon many other problems currently imaginable and non-imaginable. (If you are writing in C++, it seems you will have other issues to deal with due to POSIX thread cancellation's close association with exception handling.)