# pthread clean up handler

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have some dynamic allocations which I want to make sure are freed when the thread exits/terminates.

Please consider the following scenario:

```
static void thread_cleanup_handler(void* arg)
{
    free(arg);
}

static void* threadFunction(void* arg)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(thread_cleanup_handler, arg);
    //do some work with arg...
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return NULL;
}

something* data = (something*)malloc(sizeof(something));
pthread_create(&id, &attr, threadFunction, (void*)data); //thread is created detached
```

Question is, if the created thread is cancelled (using **pthread_cancel**) before it actually started running (it has only been scheduled and has not been executed yet), will the cleanup handler be invoked or is this a potential memory leak?

Please not that the thread is created with PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the POSIX reference for `pthread_cancel`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html):

> When the cancellation is acted on, the cancellation cleanup handlers for *thread* shall be called.

So if the thread is canceled any *installed* cleanup handlers will be run. The problem with your code is that if the thread function haven't yet called `pthread_cleanup_push` then there are no cleanup handlers to run. Leading, as you suspect, to a leak.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of, any possible solutions/suggestions?

Comment: @Tsef I *think* you don't actually have to worry about it. Calling `pthread_cancel` doesn't actually cancel the thread immediately. Instead the thread have to reach a *cancelation point*, and with your example I don't think there's a cancelation point before the "call" to `pthread_cleanup_push`. Therefore you will never have a leak, since the cleanup handler will have been registered before the first possible cancelation point.

Comment: Some more related info here if anyone needs (the thread must necessarily run to be cancelled): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719933/when-is-posix-thread-cancellation-not-immediate

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no leak.

> POSIX.1 specifies that certain functions must, and certain other
> functions may, be cancellation points.  If a thread is cancelable...then the thread is canceled when it calls a function
> that is a cancellation point.

— [pthreads(7), Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man7/pthreads.7.html)

So, your thread will run until it invokes a syscall which has been defined as a "cancellation point"—usually these are blocking syscalls.  See [a list of cancellation points](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_05_02) here; the true list is OS-dependent.

This assumes that your thread's [cancelability type](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_setcancelstate.html) is set to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`, which is the default state. If you set the cancability type to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS`, you risk a leak.